# Error in ballerina Sql connector configurations

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I have an issue with the mysql connector when i'm trying to make a connection with a staging database. There is no issue with the connection when I try locally. The error is attached below

[image: error which occurs]

The staging Db configs are as follows.

> [mysqld] max_allowed_packet=1G

Thanks!

Comment: There was an issue with the firewall. And i was able to sort out this issue.
Thank you!